# Differences in predictive accuracy when running randomForest in R

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction

I am running the below `randomForest` model in R, and am getting very good OOB results when predicting the test set (80-90% accuracy depending on how much data the model has to work with).

However, when attempting to predict `new.data`, the results, when checked with the actual outcome as soon as it becomes known, reduces the accuracy to a coin flip.

Below are examples of how the `trainDF`, `testDF` and `new.data` sets look like. The variable to be predicted, `X5fwd`, is a binary variable.

```
> trainDF
   X5fwd  Var1   Var2    Var3    Var4   Var5  Var6   Var7
3    0   139.50  9880.0  123.65  4180  206.0  1525  245.7477
4    1   137.90  9844.0  123.80  4190  206.0  1523  244.0442
7    1   139.80  9844.0  125.44  4190  204.0  1506  242.8183
9    1   142.50  9914.0  125.34  4200  204.0  1496  240.4294
10   1   143.50  9914.0  126.22  4210  204.0  1482  242.1602
11   1   143.10  9914.0  124.97  4210  204.0  1479  240.9533
14   1   143.70  9887.0  125.71  4200  205.0  1449  247.8008
15   1   143.70  9887.0  124.12  4190  205.0  1416  245.2176

> testDF[2:8]
    Var1  Var2   Var3   Var4  Var5  Var6  Var7
5   138.2  9844  121.98  4190  205  1516  240.96
17  143.8  9887  123.14  4220  205  1384  243.28
19  144.1  9827  125.65  4220  206  1354  246.72
21  144.5  9827  124.16  4240  202  1361  243.49
22  144.6  9827  122.39  4240  202  1386  243.11
24  147.1  9803  124.86  4240  202  1456  242.69
29  149.1  9785  120.18  4260  204  1561  242.74
30  148.9  9785  121.71  4280  204  1576  245.70
...
105 128.5  10045 106.20  3690  184  1200  229.83


> new.data
    Var1  Var2   Var3   Var4  Var5  Var6  Var7        
110  116  10050  109.55  3650  172  1214  230.31
```

What I don't understand is why the model cannot predict `new.data`, which consists of one row, but does well on the `testDF` dataset, considering the latter is not temporally dependent and completely removed from the training set, much like `new.data`.

Aside from the `class` and `prob`, the two sets are predicted in exactly the same way.

```
system.time(for (x in 100:(d-5)) {
  VarDataFrame <- DataFrame[1:x,]
  new.data <- DataFrame[2:8][x+5,]

  for (i in 1:100) {
    ##create the test and train data set
    ind <- sample.split(Y = VarDataFrame$X5fwd, SplitRatio = 0.7)
    trainDF <- VarDataFrame[ind,]
    testDF <- VarDataFrame[!ind,]

    ##Fitting the model
    modelRandom <- randomForest(X5fwd~., data = trainDF, mtry = 2, ntree = 200
                        , importance = TRUE)

    ##predictions test set
    PredictionsWithClass <- predict(modelRandom, testDF[2:8], type = 'class')
    t <- table(predictions=PredictionsWithClass, actual = testDF$X5fwd)

    ##accuracy metric and prediction
    Accuracy[i,] <- sum(diag(t))/sum(t)
    Output[i,] <- predict(modelRandom, new.data, type = 'prob')
  }

  ##Store Output in Matrix
  MeanAccuracy[x+5,] <- (mean(Accuracy))
  MeanOutput[x+5,] <- c(mean(Output[,1]), mean(Output[,2]))

  for(y in seq_along(x)) x[y] <- x[y]+1 
 })
```

PS: The unconventional loops are there to get average results using different seeds, and to allow me to simulate running the model over time with an increasing amount of data.

**EDIT:**
As requested, here are graphs visualizing the data predictions and errors:

[image][image]

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the distributions of `trainDF` with a near complete dataset, and the `new.data` for comparison, along with the importance statistics of the fitted model.

```
> new.data
        Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4   Var5  Var6   Var7  
1295    68.72   13289   50.46   3320   186   1668   140.0435834

> importance(modelRandom)
               0        1 MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Var1    24.43001 25.23817             41.53475         80.14703
Var2    24.31617 27.30719             39.10255         63.99267
Var3    19.63059 15.39908             33.67201         67.89350
Var4    19.56362 18.09402             33.88818         53.32912
Var5    18.34156 19.21491             32.38921         56.62850
Var6    21.89851 21.29452             31.52016         65.17518
Var7    15.21747 16.06692             27.01031         62.28704
```

[image]

Comment: Has `new.data` only one row ?

Comment: @MarcoSandri yes it does. Sorry, should have specified.

Comment: Could you plot a histogram with the prediction errors for each row of  `testDF` and the value of the prediction error for `new.data`?

Comment: How many observations do you have with `trainDF[2:8]` and `testDF[2:8]`? If it's not a lot (and they are along the lines what you printed out above), I would say the `new.data` observation isn't well represented by the model you've trained. If that's true, you face a common problem in ML: you need more data.

Comment: @Val The `trainDF` and `testDF` set are split on a 70/30 basis with the total dataset containing 1290 rows. Granted, the early stages of the loop above restricts the data to 100 observations (which I agree is too little), but that is trivial to increase. The problems remain when the model has all, or close to all, available data.

Comment: I might be asking the obvious, but I'm getting a bit confused: What are you trying to predict? Classes? Probabilities? How does `X5fwd`look like?

Comment: @Val No wonder you're confused! Hope my edited question gives a better picture of how the data looks like.

Comment: @youjustreadthis,  you wrote that `new.data` has only 1 row, but your graphs show that it has many more. Please, clarify me this point.

Comment: @MarcoSandri It looks like that in the graph as a result of the model having been run multiple times, where for each run (of the main for loop) a new 'new.data' is used along with a slightly larger data set for both test and training data.

Comment: It's tricky to say anything without having a look at the whole dataset. But I would be interested to see, which the most important features for your model are and how the `new.data` observation falls into the distribution of these variables you used for training the model. As I mentioned above, your model might just be overfitted

Comment: @MarcoSandri Yes, `new.data` is held outside `trainDF` and `testDF`.
@Val Please see the second edit in the question. Hopefully that was what you meant.